# Azure SignalR "Resource is in a failed state" - how to diagnose the problem?

Tags: azure, azure-signalr

User reported a failure of one of our Blazor Server apps an hour or so ago. When I investigated it seemed the Azure SignalR service was responding with "502 Bad Gateway" to the initial OPTIONS on the signalr hub negotiation (signalr is separate to the webapp that hosts the site)

In azure manpo, this shows for the SignalR service:

[image]

Restarting it does not succeed. Clicking "view activity logs" in the "the resource is ina  failed state" banner simply brings a "Code: 'invalidRG'" message

[image]

The only significant event recently on this subscription was that it converted from a Free-Trial to Pay-as-you-go and there were some issues transitioning (upgrade done post subscription disable for lack of payment method, took some time to get it reactivated), but then everything seemed to work well for a day

There are many other services in the same resource group, apparently working fine - it's just SignalR. The "Azure status" page shows that all SignalR services are in "Good" condition.

Where does one go from here to diagnose and fix this? Is it a "pay for support from MS and ask them"?

Comment: currently having a similar issue - `The server returned status code '502' when status code '101' was expected..` - although on the Free-Trial and restarting worked fine - I guess I'll just have to wait and see if it resolves itself...

Comment: Yeah... Same issue here. I'm also getting CORS errors even when allowed origings are specified in Azure portal.

Comment: Getting same issue! Using Free-Trial.
(As a workaround we created a new SignalR Service component which we were able to connect to ok --but now we wait for it to fail in similar fashion for similar unknown reason!!)

Comment: @Miron yes, I believe the CORS error comes from the fact that though the service is failed it's still returning a response (502) that doesn't have an Allow-Origin header and the browser is treating it as a CORS fail as a result. The CORS error is a slight red herring as a result - you'll probably find (like i also did) that your signalR service has an `Allow *` set, but it's never getting as far as to be able to send that because something else is failing first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it wasn't a billing issue I wrote on the end of my billing support ticket that I'd raised to get a payment method problem sorted out during subscription upgrade. Support wrote back acknowledging a problem with the Azure SignalR service that was actively being worked on. They claimed that it was already resolved by the time they read my ticket update..

..I don't believe the staus dashboard ever showed AzSignalR as anything other than healthy so it might be that it makes sense to sign up for at least developer support level so there is a route for reporting these things. Either that or (depending on one's moral compass) raise them as billing requests (which are free) if one feels that service availability is a billing related thing (and I suppose it should be; they can't reasonably charge you for services they aren't providing, even if it is only a few cents)

Answer (score 1):

rca in progress

Azure Signal R - Service availability/management operation failures - Mitigated

Resolved: An Azure service issue (Tracking ID 1L_L-NZG) impacted resources in your subscription.
Summary of impact: Between 06:00 and 14:00 UTC on 21 Jul 2021, you were identified as a customer using Azure SignalR Service who may have received failure notifications when attempting to connect or access resources. Additionally, failures may have been seen when attempting to perform service management operations - such as create, update, delete.